# how to use opposite of ng-model in angular 2 - Get value from interpolation and use into another field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

First I am having a div, which is having a lot of calculations like this.

```
     <div id = "div1"> {{ 4}} * {{ 5 }} * {{6}} </div> 
--- and a lot of multiplications, all of these data is coming from backend.
```

Now, I do have another div(div2), which want to use the result of this div1 and do other calculations.

```
 <div id = "div2"> {{ result of div1}} * {{ 15 }} * {{16}} </div>
```

And then again, Now, I do have another div, which want to use the result of this div1 and do other calculations.

```
 <div id = "div3"> {{ result of div2}} * {{ 25 }} * {{26}} </div>
```

Note: I can not do this multiplication in .ts file. 
4,5,6,15,16,25,26 are static values, I just tried to put more simple as possible.

```
<div id = "div1">{{ var1* var2* var3}}</div> <div id = "div2">{{ var1* var2* var3}} * {{var4*var5}}</div> <div id = "div3">{{ var1* var2* var3}} * {{var4*var5}} * {{var6}}</div>


I think I need to use, ng-model, but, I do not know, how to use that thing here.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: why can't you do the multiplication in your component? this is awful.

Comment: is 4, 5 and 6 is your initial variable?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot No, 4,5,6,15,16,25,26 are just values, I do have multiple values,

Comment: @lexith, I have clearly mentioned, I can not use them on the component side.

Comment: yea you mentioned it, but why? they have to be defined there, otherwise you couldn't use them in your component, right? ...

Comment: I am having multiple loops on the page which are having if, else conditions, Now instead of creating all logic in the component file and creating n times- variable, I am directly using the value on HTML file.

Comment: Perfect example of the XY Problem. Btw, ngModel does only work with a defined property in your component and there is no way to use local template variables like you want to do. Just think of a proper object structure to store your results so that you can easily access them in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operation can not be done as you mentioned in question. Find possible way below As you said they are static values.

```
<div id = "div1">{{4*5*6}}</div>
<div id = "div2">{{(4*5*6)*15*16}}</div>
<div id = "div3">{{((4*5*6)*15*16)*25*26}}</div>
```

Comment: they are not static values, Instead of consider them like this. 
`<div id = "div1">{{ var1* var2* var3}}</div>
<div id = "div2">{{ var1* var2* var3}} * {{var4*var5}}</div>
<div id = "div3">{{ var1* var2* var3}} * {{var4*var5}} * {{var6}}</div>`